# OneDrive doesn't download files despite having the option enabled

Tags: download, automation, onedrive

I have following option ticked in OneDrive on my desktop computer:

[image: OneDrive Settings]

When I upload files from my phone, OneDrive shows this on my computer:

[image: File statuses]

Those files with little cloud icon are not downloaded, they are kept on OneDrive servers until I actually try to access them. How do I tell OneDrive that I really want it to download entire contents of my account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark a file or folder for offline use or as online-only:

1. Right-click a file or folder.
2. Choose to ‘Always keep on this device’ or ‘Free up space.’

[Learn about OneDrive Files On-Demand](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-about-onedrive-files-on-demand-0e6860d3-d9f3-4971-b321-7092438fb38e)

Comment: Marking as answer as the provided link is actually useful and provides step by step instructions on how to disable this feature.